# No Output from Boost Test

Tags: unit-testing, boost, boost-test

I am trying to implement unit test with boost test libraries. I started by reading the manual at the boost site. After this i make a simple test program in one of my already existing project. The only problem which i face is that i am unable to see the test result. I am sure that i am making some thing wrong :) but i am unable to figure that. Following are the details of my project

I am using visual studio8 for this:
I have a solution named **MyProject.sln**

Along with other projects i have a project named **MyDLL.vcproj** (The type of this project is **DLL**)

Along with other files in MYDLL proj i add a new cpp file name **MyTest.cpp**, the file contains the following code:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
//#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTestTestModue  //no need for this maro if above macro is used
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SampleTC)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
};
```

I make following changes in MYDLL project property sheet

```
C++ -> General -> Additional Include Dependencies = D:\MyProject\Boost\boost\test
Linker -> General -> Additional Libray Directories = D:\MyProject\Boost\lib\win32\Debug
Linker -> System -> SubSystem = (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)
```

I read all the compilation details given in the manual, but still unable to get the output. Ideally i want to use the Boost test as a standalone lib (Dynamic library varian of UTF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am sure that i am making some thing
>   wrong :)

Actually, I think the problem is you are making something right.

Your test passes, because the value checked is `true`, and by default Boost.Test only outputs information about tests that have failed.  You need to set the log level, which can be done one of two ways: passing `--log_level=all` as an option the the test executable, or setting the environment variable `BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL` to `all`.

See [this page of the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html) for all the run time parameters.

Edit: It's actually --log_level (with an underscore in the middle)

Answer (score 1):

Our unit tests are called via a tool post-compile; so we cannot easily pass a parameter to the EXE (without changing the tool configuration and affecting all tests).

So another way of setting the log-level threshold is to call the Boost unit-test logger singleton from the code:

```
boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::instance().set_threshold_level( boost::unit_test::log_messages );
```

For added fun, output the file name and line number where your message is displayed:

```
 #define MY_BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( msg ) BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( `__FILE__` << `__LINE__` << " " << msg )
```